# Rounded values in iOS-charts

Tags: ios-charts

I'm using ios-chart library, when I set this:

set1.drawValuesEnabled = true

in LineChartDataSet, my values are rounded as Int value (Example: 5.4 to 5)

This happen only when a get the values from api service, I convert the values of my array from String to Double

I'm printing the values before I assign to dataset and the values are correct. I don't want rounded values

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use custom `valueFormatter` in dataSet objects.

Comment: I finally use this:

let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
set1.valueFormatter = numberFormatter

and it work! Thanks